# In a trigger, does assigning a column to the "old" value incur a cost? (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, optimization, trigger

For the sake of readability, in one of my triggers I have `:new.COLUMNNAME := old.COLUMNNAME;` alongside the sets for the rest of the columns. Does this statement get removed before runtime? (That column is not assigned anywhere earlier in the trigger)

We're doing this because depending on the value of `typecolumn`, other columns will or will not have values, and those values are found on another table... It's not exactly good sql using all the features as they were intended to be used, or good db design, but this is an old codebase and we have to play the hand we're dealt.

I want to set all the columns, even if the value doesn't change, for the sake of clarity and readability so that people know that we didn't just forget a column. The lead dev is hesitant to do that because he's worried about the performance impact of extra lines in a trigger (which will get called many times), but if I can prove that the lines have no effect then he'll be placated.

Here's a little more (simplified) context to hopefully illustrate what I mean.

```sql
create or replace trigger SCHEMA.TRIGGERNAME
before insert on SCHEMA.TABLENAME1
for each row
declare mno1 number
begin
  select min(mno2), min(data22), min(data32)
    into mno1, data2, data3
    from (select mno as mno2, data2 as data22, data3 as data32
      from SCHEMA.TABLENAME2 t2
        inner join SCHEMA.TABLENAME3 t3
          on t2.somekey = t3.somekey);

  case :new.typecolumn
    when 1 then
      :new.mno := mno1;
      :new.data2 := :old.data2;
      :new.data3 := :old.data3;
    when 2 then
      :new.mno := :old.mno;
      :new.data2 := data2;
      :new.data3 := data3;
    end case;
end;
```

Comment: I would seriously doubt that it would. While your subject mentions default values for columns (something that can be defined at table creation) your question is about assigning a value to a variable within a pl/sql block. I can't imagine any benefit to having the compiler detect that and remove the instruction from the compiled code.  And given how few machine cycles would be necessary to make that assignment, I can't imagine any benefit.  How much effort is justified to make 'n'% reduction in run-time of code that already executes in a just a few nano-seconds?

Comment: I'd like to see that line within a Trigger.  At first glance, your posted code is overwriting the value that the `INSERT` statement set for `NULLABLE_COLUMN`.

Comment: I've updated the post with some more context

Comment: `:new.data2 := :old.data2;` would seem to override the value of `data2` in the `insert` statement and force it to be NULL in which case it would have to be executed.  In this example, though, I'd expect the query against `table2` and `table3` would be so vastly more expensive than the `:new` pseudorecord assignments that it would make no sense to worry about the performance of the latter.

Comment: Yeah, I know the extra assignment is trivial to performance, but I'm not the decision maker and the decision maker insists.